# SQL SUM query group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the below simple query:-

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vwPAProjects_Summary_New_2
```

which generates data in the following output:-

[image]

can anyone advise as to the best way to code in that when the 'PACONTNUMBER' and 'Project Type' is the same perform a sum to provide an overall total for each numerical value.

Example:-

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include your latest attempt at a solution. Folks will then point you in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: your question is not clear, please put some efforts to make it clear

Comment: you should group by pacontnumber and then sum the column you want to add

Comment: Can you send me a magnifying glass please?

Comment: unfortunately its the way it comes out when uploaded to the site.  Thanks for all your help I have cracked it.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT PACONTNUMBER, Project Type,
SUM(Project_Fee_Amount) AS Project_Fee_Amount
FROM dbo.vwPAProjects_Summary_New_2
GROUP BY PACONTNUMBER, Project Type
```

And then add any other fields you would like to SUM to the select list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to list all of your fields (don't use '*').

Then use the SUM() function on what you want summed.

Then, everything beyond the ProjectFeeAmount field will either need to be excluded from your list, or aggregated somehow (sum, min, max, etc.).

```
SELECT
   Contract,
   Sum(PAContNumber) as SumOfPAContNumber,
   ProjectManagerID,
   ...
FROM
   ...
GROUP BY
   Contract,
   ProjectManagerID,
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started, you will need to add other `SUM` lines for the other values you want totalled

```
select   PACONTNUMBER, 
         [Project Type], 
         sum([Project Fee Amount) as TotalProjectFees
from     vwProjects_Summary_New_2
group by PACONTNUMBER, 
         [Project Type]
```